# fadeIn works as show() in some div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show, fadein

I'm using jquery in my webpage but fadeIn and fadeOut doesn't work after the first two times. i had tried with show(500,...), hide and animate, with easing and without it, but it behaves the same.
here is one of the div's i want to fadeIn

```
    <div id="rfcdiv" style="position: absolute; display: none" >  
<img alt="Ticket" src="images/DATOSfiscales.png" style="position:absolute;width:fit-content;left:0px;top:230px;z-index:18"></img>
<div id="text1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:45px; top:341px; width:37px; height:21px; z-index:20"><div class="wpmd"><div><font face="Myriad Pro Light"><B>RFC:</B></font></div></div></div>
<input name="RFC" id="RFC" type="text" maxlength=13 value="<?php if (isset($_GET['rfc'])){echo $_GET['rfc'];}?>" style="position:absolute;width:276px;left:79px;top:340px;z-index:13">
<div id="ValidacionRfc" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:360px; top:341px;width: fit-content;height: fit-content;z-index:14;display: none" onmouseover="mostrarglobo(1)" onmouseout="mostrarglobo(0)"></div>
```

here is the code that shows it:

```
 $("#image1").animate({ height: "450px" }, 800, function () {
 $("#ingresarfolio").animate({ top: "170px" }, 800,  function () {
      $('#rfcdiv').fadeIn(500, function () {
                           recheck_ticket(1);
      });
   });
```

});

you can try here: [MyPage](http://tytsoftwaredemexico.com/Facturar.php?folio=520210109)
(just pressing Enter on the textbox)

//apologize about my english

edit:
When the page loads it fades in correctly, if you put a leter on the textbox it will fadein an icon  correctly but when you only press enter it will just appear after a time.

**Sorry, i cant show the code correctly** so the code is the first commented code in MyPage

Comment: The first box fades in fine. What's the second step of the demo?

Comment: wher is the fadeOut()??

Comment: it starts with display:none
isherwood-> does it work fine in your pc? i have tested in some other pc's and it works like a delay and then a show();

Comment: Getting this with Firebug: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: @APAD1 relevance of SQL syntax here??

Comment: seems to be weird absolute positioning. the container you are **faiding in** is actually somewhere else in the page.

Comment: is it because of the left:px? y center the main container when the page is just loaded.
`$('#container').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - 955) / 2,
                top: 0
            });

            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('#container').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: ($(window).width() - 955) / 2,
                    top: 0
                });
            });`

Comment: @user3100334 have you tried my answer. let me know if it not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In you script (facturar.js)**

the fadeIn syntax is

```
$('#rfcdiv').fadeIn(function () {
                   recheck_ticket(1);
 }, 2000);
```

try **changing it to**

```
$('#rfcdiv').fadeIn(2000, function () {
                recheck_ticket(1);
     });
```

Refer **[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)**

**Then,**

Remove `position:absolute` from  all components inside `#rfcdiv` and let them placed in document flow.

and position `#rfcdiv` whereever you want by applying `position:absolute`, `top` and `left` to it.

like this

```
#rfcdiv {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I had it like that but in the last answer @Cam said i should change it. i re-corrected that line.. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: just go through the reference i have attached

Comment: @user3100334 just update with this and try, and even if you have issue let me have a check with your live site with this update in your script

Comment: you have typeError in your console because of this, check console. So update your script

Comment: thanks, i was using that syntax but i changed because of the last answer. Can you see something else?:(

Comment: now we have only that one. Could you pls update your live url with the new syntax. So that i can check and confirm

Comment: @user3100334 i have updated my answer. check with my suggestion. You can see the fadeIn working. But when you remove absolute positions you may find your design broken. but just test with my update, after that put these elemetns in document flow.

Comment: remove position:absolute from components inside `#rfcdiv` only. You can preserve position:absolute of `#rfcdiv`

Comment: Wow! fade in now works perfectly, but how do i change the position of the elements now D:?

Comment: @user3100334 i just shown there how you can place it anywhere in the page. You can change top & left values accordingly

Comment: @user3100334 its really an improper way of designing a website. You are not suppose to use absolute positions in such a manner. You have to maintain a document flow.

Comment: i still cant position the elements, i know, it was designed with "webpagemaker"(or something like that) and then i was asked to make it work.

Comment: i am unable to predict those positions, it will differ from devices, these kind of position abolutes will change its positions according to device resolutions on which it is viewed, you have to use these inside relative positioned containers to avoid that. You have to refer more on absolute and relative positions to do that. Moreover this design you can simply do without any of these complex position tricks. You have to refer more

Comment: try applying `#text1, #RFC {margin-left:50px;}`. This one is as per my device. Check whether it satisfies you

Comment: read more on layouting, refer these articles [absolute position](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-absolute-positioning/), [document flow](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/css-understanding-document-flow.html). and you can accept my answer if it helped you by checking the tick mark lies left to my answer.

Comment: thank you man, the next time i design a page i'll make it by myself. by now i fixed it in a diferent way `        function o_mRFC(b,t){
            if(b){
                $("#banDatosF").fadeIn(t);
                $("#text1").fadeIn(t);
                $("#RFC").fadeIn(t);
            }else{
                $("#banDatosF").fadeOut(t);
                $("#text1").fadeOut(t);
                $("#RFC").fadeOut(t);                
            }
            
        }`

Answer (score -1):

From my first look without going to your website, your timing is incorrect. See edit below.

```
  $('#rfcdiv').fadeIn(function () {
                       recheck_ticket(1);
  }, 500);
```

Comment: It looks like you dont have all your code in there, is there anything you are missing. Because it looks like you need to create a function, then run the function.  Cause what you have up top gives me no indication of what your doing. Like what is recheck_ticket.

Comment: rechek_ticket is a lock that avoids repeating the process until it is finished